# Can multiple inheritance be achieved in C# using interfaces?

Tags: c#, interface, abstract-class, multiple-inheritance

I often encounter in articles which describe abstract class and interface, that C# does not support multiple inheritance but can be achieved using interfaces. I don't agree to that for the following reasons

1. We always inherit the state and behavior from any class.
2. Interface does not define the state or behavior.
3. We cannot inherit anything from an interface but always implement it.

So bottom line is that C# does not support multiple inheritance and interfaces cannot help us achieve multiple inheritance (in fact we can never inherit from an interface).

Comment: We can inherit from an interface with other interface ;)

Comment: Is this purely academical question or are you encountering some real world problem you would like to solve?

Comment: Is there a question in there, or did you just want to say that you disagree?

Comment: There is no question here, just a statement. +1 vote to close.

Comment: The implied question is : Is this statement correct? And I think it was kind of valid. But probably a dupe.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can not implement multiple inheritance in C#, period.

You can, however, get *some* of the benefits of multiple inheritance through interfaces, namely the part where you can add contracts to a class to make it fit other parts of the system, the substitution principle.

But no, you can not get the part where you inherit behavior from multiple base classes.

Answer (score 1):

> in fact we can never inherit from an interface

Disputable. "Inheriting" from an interface is a way of viewing it. It does satisfy the substitution principle.

But I agree that "Implementing" an interface is a more common expression/view.